# List all the users who have logs of more than 1 days

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Our database is MongoDB. I have a list of logs of users. A log is as follows:

```
{
    "userId" : ObjectId("5a176fa24d96415280e22cc8"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-12-10T15:36:45.566Z"),
    ... ...
}
```

Now, I would like to **list all the revisiting users (those who have logs of more than 1 days)**.

Could anyone give me some hint to write this MongoDB shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `$expr` Operator inside the match Pipeline to perform the day calculation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "min": {
        "$min": "$date"
      },
      "max": {
        "$max": "$date"
      },
    },
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gte": [
          "$max",
          {
            "$add": [
              "$min",
              86400000
            ]
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bKcOWIoff4-)

Comment: I'm not sure it is the solution. I tried: https://mongoplayground.net/p/y2r9bJkY0T3. I expected to return only the user `5a176fa24d96415280e22cc8`.

Comment: @SoftTimur Apologise for the inconvenience, I misunderstood the answer. I have updated my answer